# How to put 4 independent figures in a row in latex

Tags: floats

My code is able to print 4 figures in a row in 2 column format. But the thing is these are sub figure but my figures are not sub figures they are independent of each other. I tried to remove subfloat but its throwing error

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=.49\linewidth} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
        \subfloat[AAO]{\label{Fig5:A}\includegraphics{A.png}}\hfill
        \subfloat[BB]{\label{Fig5:B}\includegraphics{B.png}}
        \caption{A and B} \label{Fig5:AB}
    \end{minipage}\hfill % be sure not to leave a blank line
    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\columnwidth}
        \subfloat[C]{\label{Fig6:c}\includegraphics{C.png}}\hfill 
        \subfloat[D]{\label{Fig6:D}\includegraphics{D.png}}
        \caption{C and D} \label{Fig6:CD}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Please clarify your formatting objecitve. E.g., are their four separate figures (with one graph per figure), two separate figures (with two graphis per figure), or something else?

Comment: its separate figures that why i wrote independent not sub figures

Comment: Thanks. Are there four separate figures, or just two?

Comment: four separate figures that why i wrote 4 independent figures in title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following?

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, demo]{report} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{A}
\caption{A} \label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{B}
\caption{B} \label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{C}
\caption{C} \label{fig:c}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{D}
\caption{D} \label{fig:d}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One more solution with arranged figures in table (using `tabularray` package), but with use of captions that image can be referenced in text...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter,varwidth}   % <===


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure*}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=4pt,
             colspec={@{} *{4}{X[c]}@{}}, 
             measure = vbox}
    \includegraphics{A}
\caption{A} \label{fig:a}
    &
    \includegraphics{B}
\caption{B} \label{fig:b}
    &
    \includegraphics{C}
\caption{C} \label{fig:c}
    &
    \includegraphics{D}
\caption{D} \label{fig:d}
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

4 figures in a table with 4 columns:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,mwe}

\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out amount of intercol. whitespace
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc}  
  \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image-a}
& \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image-b} 
& \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image-c}  
& \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{example-image-a} \\
  Fig. 1 A & Fig. 2 B & Fig. 3 C & Fig. 4 D\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: With this setup, one can't use the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism to cross-reference the figures. Worse, the total width of the `tabular` environment is `0.96+8\tabcolsep`, so there's no guarantee that its width is less than `\textwidth`. Please  fix.

Comment: @Mico Your answer is a pro (guru?) answer for a complex document. Mine is one more simpler for a simpler document. One can override the \textwidth problem choosing for each column .22\textwidth.

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to employ a `tabular*` environment. That way, the material is guaranteed to fit inside the text block. Feel free to revert.